# How to remove questions listed under "Top Network Posts" or "Top Questions" from my profile

Tags: support, profile-page, top-questions

In my profile, I want to remove some of the questions listed under "Top Network Posts" or "Top Questions".

I don't want to delete the questions/posts themselves because I think they're valuable for others to read; rather, I just don't want them displayed on my profile.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can hide the site(s) where you posted the question(s) from your profile, and as a side effect this will also hide your top questions from those sites from your profile.

To hide a site, go to [your profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=profile) (no matter where) and click "edit list" below your communities list:

> [image: user's communities list edit button]

This will open [Hidden Communities page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/hidecommunities/current) where you can choose what sites to hide:

> [image: hiding sites from profile]

That's it. Once clicking "Hide" it takes instant effect. You can always unhide any site in the bottom of the same page.